# Should I use "to" in this sentence after the conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, to-infinitive

I wrote:

> How is it possible to be a mother and **[to]** see your child is being killed in such a horrible way? **to see** them beating your child's head to a wall until his brain **pours out**.

The first part of the conjunction "to be" has "to" should I then use "to" before "see"?

What about "to see" in the beginning of the second sentence? Can a sentence begin like that?

And finally, what is the proper verb for "pours out"...

P.S. I am translating the feelings of someone about a book on WW II.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your query a bit at a time:

It's not necessary to repeat **to** but you can do so if you wish.

However, your sentence would read more easily if you omit the word **is**

> How is it possible to be a mother and **[to]** see your child being killed in such a horrible way?

Other readers might comment that there are no pleasant ways to see your child being killed but that would have nothing to do with grammar.

The second part of your sentence needs to be separated from the first, not by a full stop but a semi-colon (;) if it's to follow on directly.

> to see them beating your child's head to a wall until his brain pours out.

This assumes that you have already identified the people you refer to as **them**

The word **child** is neuter and while it's quite correct subsequently to use the masculine pronoun **his**, which identifies the child as a boy, others might prefer to speak of **its head** or **their head**. This is just a matter of preference.

The child's head would be beaten (or *dashed*) **against** the wall rather than **to** the wall.

There's nothing wrong with **pours out**.Even though brains are normally more like a pasta than a liquid, under the circumstances they might well pour out.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by "repeat preposition"? I thought the "to" is for making infinitive.

Comment: Fair comment - I've deleted *preposition*. While **to** is frequently used as a preposition (to the gate), it is not acting as a preposition when it precedes a verb to form an infinitive. See: http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html